# Question involving Taylor series and continuity

Tags: continuity, taylor-expansion

Question:

> $$f(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{x^{2n}-1}{x^{2n}+1}$$

Where is this function continuous?

Trial:
I analyzed positive terms of x.For large values of n the function approaches to 1 for $x>1$. For $x=1$ the function approaches 0, and the approaches to -1 for $x<1$. I really can't understand what it has got to do with Taylor series, because the question is about Taylor series plus I think the answer is " it is continuous for all x", but I doubt it. It would be great if someone would explain!?

Comment: Very sorry, made an edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function is
$$f(x) = \left\{ \begin{matrix}
1 && x>1 \\ 0 && x=1 \\ -1 && 0<x<1
\end{matrix} \right.$$
so it is discontinuous at $x=1$.

So you can see an example of analytic functions $f_n \to f$ (pointwise convergence) converging to a discontinuous function. In particular pointwise convergence does not assure you that the limit is analytic and the sequence of Taylor series converges to a Taylor series.

Comment: I saw the term "analytic functions on both answers, I am not aware of such a function ?"

Comment: An analytic function is simply something equal to its Taylor series.

Answer (score 1):

For a finite $n$, it's an analytic function, it's continuous everywhere it's defined. It has $2n$ poles on the unit circle, so the Taylor series will have the radius of convergence $1$.

EDIT:

In the limit, the function does become discontinuous, but the Taylor series in principle should hold for $|x|<1$, as for all finite $n$, the radius of convergence remains the same. The Taylor series equals the function value for $|x|<1$. If you used an asymptotic series (develop over $1/x$), you would get the correct convergence for $|x|>1$. The $x=1$ is a special case, where the function is undefined.

Comment: "2n poles on the unit circle..." What does this mean?

Comment: If the radius of convergence is 1 doesn't it mean $abs(x)<1$

Comment: The denominator $x^{2n}+1$ is a polynomial with $2n$ zeros in complex numbers (even though there are no real zeroes). If you rewrite $x^{2n}=-1$ and take the absolute value, you see that the absolute value of $x$ has to be $1$, so all $x$ that solve the equation have unit length. Taylor series converges of analytic functions converge to the first pole they encounter, so it converges on $|x|<1$. Even if you don't see the poles in the reals, the complex poles limit the radius of convergence.

Comment: @orion Please see the edit to the question.